# enroll iphone developer program personally?

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

Is it possible for me to enroll in the iPhone developer program without being under a business or company?

If yes, what are the requirements? Do I need a supporting website or anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enroll as an individual or company.

We are enrolled as a company, so I don't know the specifics of what you need to enroll as an individual.

You definitely need a web site and a method for customers to contact you for support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Like TwistedAphid mentioned, I would put a website together for sure.  I believe it cost around $90 for me to do it a while back.  The good thing is that you can start developing without being registered or accepted.

Comment: the supporting site can just a blog?

Comment: @ying - That would probably be a question for Apple. We have a web site with a support email address for customers to contact us.